# Unable to use LeakCanary to watch a fragment (ClassCastException error)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an issue with a memory leak in my app and I read about LeakCanary so I tried to set it up.

In my app, I have one activity that contains two fragments, and I'm trying to watch the first fragment only for leaks. This is how I set it up:

I made this Java class to contain the LeakCanary logic.

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {
public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
    ExampleApplication application = (ExampleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    return application.refWatcher;
}

private RefWatcher refWatcher;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
}
```

}

I then added this  to my fragment's OnDestroy:

```
 @Override public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = ExampleApplication.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
    refWatcher.watch(MainFragment.this);
}
```

When I destroy the activity containing the fragment, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to projectname.ExampleApplication
```

I have searched Google and the documentation extensively, but I can't find anyone else who has encountered this error. I'm at a loss for what to do, but I'd really like to use this tool. If anyone has any advice, I'd truly appreciate it.

Comment: very weird..i have exactly the same code and i do not get any errors..in what android version is your app running?

Comment: minSdkVersion 19, 
targetSdkVersion 24,  compileSdkVersion 24. It is very odd indeed, I will keep messing around with it to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: i have just updated leak canary dependencies to test my app in android Marshmallow...                                                                             debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'

Answer (score 2):

you need to mention the name of Application subclass (Exampleapplication, in your case) in the manifest file to get it working, if the name is not mentioned, android will use base class instead (that is,Application) and then a class-cast operation will throw an exception when you try to do this

```
ExampleApplication application = (ExampleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
```

.To correct it, add this code in your manifest file, in the application tag. This code is for demo purpose.

```
<application    
android:name="ExampleApplication">
<activity/>
</application>
```

And it will work as desired.

Look here for more [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)